# Определить что все символы в строке уникальны

Tags: golang

Стоит задача, определить, что все символы в строке уникальны. На входе например

`test string`

на выходе

`test string - false`

На входе

`abcde`

на выходе

`abcde - true`

Я делаю так

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func CountLetters(str string) (bool, string) {
    slcstr := strings.Split(str, "")
    mpbool := make(map[string]bool, 0)
    for _, item := range slcstr {
        _, ok := mpbool[item]
        if ok {
            return false, str
        }
        mpbool[item] = true
    }
    return true, str
}

func main() {
    log.Println(CountLetters("test"))
}
```

Но может есть какие то еще способы или есть какой-то классический способ?
И еще меня немного смущает что медленная функция, думаю из-за пакета strings. Есть ли вариант без него  и без приведения типов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обойтись только слайсами

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(CountLetters("abcde"))
    fmt.Println(CountLetters("abcdee"))
}

func CountLetters(str string) (string, bool) {
    for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(str); j++ {
            if str[i] == str[j] {
                return str, false
            }
        }
    }

    return str, true
}
```

```
abcde true
abcdee false
```

Вариант с юникодом

```
func CountLettersUnicode(str string) (string, bool) {
    chars := []rune(str)
    length := len(chars)
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < length; j++ {
            if chars[j] == chars[i] {
                return str, false
            }
        }
    }
    return str, true
}
```

---

UPD: Сделал тест производительности. Первый вариант самый шустрый.

```
package benching

import (
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func CountLetters1(str string) (string, bool) {
    for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(str); j++ {
            if str[i] == str[j] {
                return str, false
            }
        }
    }

    return str, true
}

func CountLetters2(str string) (string, bool) {
    slcstr := strings.Split(str, "")
    mpbool := make(map[string]bool, 0)
    for _, item := range slcstr {
        _, ok := mpbool[item]
        if ok {
            return str, false
        }
        mpbool[item] = true
    }
    return str, true
}

func BenchmarkCountLetters(b *testing.B) {
    b.Run("1", func(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            CountLetters1("abcde")
        }
    })
    b.Run("2", func(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            CountLetters2("abcde")
        }
    })
}
```

```
go test -bench BenchmarkCountLetters -benchtime=10000000x -benchmem

goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: benching
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
BenchmarkCountLetters/1-8       10000000                12.96 ns/op            0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkCountLetters/2-8       10000000               331.0 ns/op            80 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      benching        3.964s
```

Comment: Вроде как по примеру, проверяется только следующий элемент

Comment: Просто из вашего варианта если строка будет acnam, то будет тру, хотя a потвторяется дважды, но не подряд

Comment: Если передать строку `acnam` результат будет `acnam false`  https://go.dev/play/p/PWYiY-0TCB4. Во вложенном цикле будет проверяться символ `a` c `cnam` и будет найдено совпадение.

Comment: что то не пойму, как? Проверяется каждый с каждым чтоли?

Comment: Да, простым перебором массива. Метод грубой силы (brute force).  Например: в первой итерации сравниваем `a` c `bcc`. Во второй `b` с `cc`. В третьей `c` с `c`.  Во вложенном цикле используем `i+1` т.к. нам не нужно проверять уже проверенные символы, включая сам символ, который проверяем.

Comment: Первый вариант шустрый только на коротких строках, не говоря уж о том, что он ещё и работает только для символов, которые в UTF-8 представляются одним байтом. Во втором варианте не надо делать `split`, сразу можно `range` по строке

Comment: Согласен, для юникода лучше использовать `rune` . Но вопрос был не про сравнение строк в юникоде ;) На длинных строках тоже хорошие показатели - в 10 раз быстрее, чем в предложенном автором вопроса варианте. `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` - на мой взгляд достаточно длинная строка. 
Я не утверждаю что это самый быстрый вариант, побитовым сдвигом или хэш таблицей наверняка будет быстрее.